# VB.NET class serializing issue

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I am trying to serialize this class with Newtonsoft.JSON but the output always result in 
`{}`
and I cannot find out why.
Is there something I have to add to this class? Shall I use something different from `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`?

```
Namespace GestioneMail
    Public Class clsOrdine
        Dim Id As Int32
        Dim Ordine As String

        Public Sub New()

        End Sub

        Sub New(Id As Int32, Ordine As String)
            Me.Id = Id
            Me.Ordine = Ordine
        End Sub

        Public Shared Function GetOrdini() As List(Of clsOrdine)
            'do things
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Id` and `Ordine` should be declared as properties.